# How can I modify JSON data returned to AngularJS from a server-side API?

Tags: jquery, cordova, angularjs-directive, drupal-7, ionic-framework

I have a public API that I created with Drupal (php content management system).  I appreciate the help I got recently from someone on getting HTML to be interpreted by AngularJS.  On a different issue, I am making a $http.get(http://example.com/api/v1/...) call in the controller and displaying the data as html data.  I am using ionic with Cordova intending to display it on a mobile device.  One of the fields is a text area and it has an image in it.  The image is a relative link.  So, that doesn't work in my app.

I need to select the image tag, or the src attribute to be more specific and concatenate the domain onto that.  I am using the Drupal Views module to get the data.  So, one option is to edit the field but I don't know how easy it would be with php to find an attribute on an img tag and alter it.

So, the other option is to work with it when I get it back.  Perhaps, I need an AngularJS Directive.  Can someone suggest some tips on this?  Do I want an isolate scope?  What kind of scope?  Should I use JQuery inside the directive to select and then modify the src attribute?
Thanks in advance for any tips,
Bruce

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding everything correctly, but are you able to modify your public API to have it send an `img src` that isn't relative?

Comment: Please show the $http code. Also is jQuery being included already on page? Sample of the html also would help. Image in a textarea sounds strange...not quite clear what that is about